# Meaning of 100 in APPROX_QUANTILES

Tags: google-bigquery

What is the meaning of 100 in APPROX_QUANTILES?

```
APPROX_QUANTILES(x, 100)[OFFSET(25)] AS cuartil_25
```

Thank you!

Comment: check out [APPROX_QUANTILES](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/approximate_aggregate_functions#approx_quantiles) -  where number (in your case `100`) represents the number of quantiles to create. This function returns an array of number + 1 elements, where the first element is the approximate minimum and the last element is the approximate maximum. Run it with few different values and you will see what they are :o)

Comment: But I don't quite understand it. If I want to obtain the quartiles 25,50,75 ... would I use 100?

Answer (score 0):

Just today, I got confused on the same lines so here's how it goes.

When you are using **Quartiles**, i.e. divide the data into 4 groups, offset will be 1, 2, 3 or 4 (not sure why would someone use 4 though) as you are seeking **quartiles** (and not **percentiles**).

**Can a quartile be achieved by setting `n = 100`?**

Yes, by setting offset = 25, 50 and 75 for 1st, 2nd and 3rd quartiles respectively.

The 1st Quartile, **Q1 is same as 25th percentile**. The second Quartile, **Q2 is same as 50th percentile** (which also is the **median**).The third Quartile, **Q3 is same as 75th percentile**.

So

> If I want to obtain the quartiles 25,50,75 ... would I use 100?

was a wrong question. You don't have 25, 50 and 75 in **Quartiles**!! They are there only in **percentiles**.

Couple of resources to read more are [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/156778/percentile-vs-quantile-vs-quartile) and [here](https://www.statsdirect.com/help/nonparametric_methods/quantiles.htm#:%7E:text=Quantiles%20are%20points%20in%20a,of%20values%20in%20that%20distribution.&text=Centiles%2Fpercentiles%20are%20descriptions%20of,sorted%20values%20of%20a%20sample).